# How to apply style button in Android?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I can never apply the style of the Facebook API in myself (Login button and share), I put in "theme" and **insert** the code styles.xml.
 The design appears but is invisible, how do I apply correctly?

sorry if it's a stupid question

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.morais.daniela.doctorquiz.AutenticationActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/xxxhdpi"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:theme="@style/com_facebook_loginview_default_style" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">@style/ButtonBar</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">@style/ButtonBarButton</item>
    </style>

    <style name="RatingBar">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="SRB_size">50sp</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Backward-compatible version of ?android:attr/buttonBarStyle -->
    <style name="ButtonBar">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/bottom_bar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="com_facebook_loginview_default_style" parent="com_facebook_button">
        <item name="android:drawableLeft">@drawable/com_facebook_button_icon</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Backward-compatible version of ?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle -->
    <style name="ButtonBarButton" />

</resources>
```

Comment: Most likely, `android:theme` is not supported for `Button` now. You'll have to inline `com_facebook_loginview_default_style` in your layout if you also want to keep `style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"`.